# json.loads formatting issue

Tags: python, json

I'm currently learning the basics behind Python. I've been tasked with creating a few simple database-related Python scripts. I'm having an issue working with JSON on my `SELECT` script.

The data format I need is as follows;

```
{
    "Data": {
        "name1": "val1",
        "name2": "val2",
        "name3": "val3",
        "name4": "val4"
    },
    "IMPORTANT_NOTE": "This data is from the test database - used for demonstration only!"
}
```

The data itself is stored as JSON within the DB so it's 1 field. The data is retrieves as follows;

```
  try:
    db = MySQLdb.connect(dbhost, dbuser, dbpass, sqldb)
  except:
    msg = "Connect error"
  else:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT JSON_DATA FROM TEST_DB_TABLE WHERE DATA_GUID= %s"
    args = "TestData"
    cursor.execute(sql,args)
    for row in curosr.fetchall() : jsondata = row[0]
  finally:
    db.close()
```

This returns the following if i `print(jsondata)`;

```
{
  "name1": "val1",
  "name2": "val2",
  "name3": "val3",
  "name4": "val4"
}
```

I'm used to PHP so I'd expect to use an array to form the rest of the data and finalize it with `json_encode`. I understand that Python's equivalents to arrays are dictionaries so I feel like that's what I should use here. I did try this at the end;

```
  data = json.loads(jsondata)
  FinOut = {"Data": data, "IMPORTANT_NOTE": "This data is from the test database - used for demonstration only!"
  print(FinOut)
```

... The issue here is that it returns invalid JSON;

```
{'Data': {u'name1': u'val1', u'name2': u'val2', u'name3': u'val3', u'name4': u'val4'}, 'IMPORTANT_NOTE': 'This data is from the test database - used for demonstration only!'}
```

I did try `json.load(jsondata)` instead but then `cgitb` reports an error (I assume because `.load` is a file-based equivalent;

```
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'str' object has no attribute 'read' 
      args = ("'str' object has no attribute 'read'",) 
      message = "'str' object has no attribute 'read'"
```

Any ideas on how I correct this to output the data in a format similar to the one at the top?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You converted your JSON object to a Python dict. Why are you expecting a dict to be valid JSON? It's not. If you want JSON, you should convert your dict back into that format:

```
json_data = json.dumps(FinOut)
```